# onclick of tabs the tab content is not visible fully (jquery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

onclick of tabs the tab-content is loading only half. Though the color of the active tab is changing. But the content is not visible fully not even the header. Below is what I tried. Please tell me where I'm going wrong. The height mentioned in the code is required for my prototype, I cannot change it.
Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
  $('.sticky > .u-tabs > li >a').click(function() {
    alert("01");

    var t = $(this).attr('data-toggle-id');
    //this is the start of our condition 
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) { 
      $('#tabs li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.maintab ul.u-tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.maintab ul.u-tabs li a {
  opacity: 0.87;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #38506d;
}

.maintab ul.u-tabs li a.active {
  color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

.header {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maintab  " id="tabs">
  <div class="sticky" class="">
    <ul class="u-tabs tabs">
      <li><a href="#tabone" class="titleactive">TABONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabtwo" class="">TABTWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabthree" class="">TABTHREE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="panel" style="height:350px;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:45px;" id="tabone">
      <div class="header">tabone_content</div>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </div>
    <div class="panel " style="height:330px;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:45px;" id="tabtwo">
      <div class="header">tabtwo_content</div>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="panel " style="height:410px; border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:45px;" id="tabthree">
      <div class="header">tabthree_content</div>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've converted your code to an SO snippet to make formatting it easier.  However it's missing the include for your `.tabs()` - which script are you using for tabs?   Please update the snippet so that it demonstrates the issue completely; see [mcve]

Comment: @freedomn-m thanq for your reply.

Comment: here is my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/user78/6ajtr72x/3/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even include jquery, let alone tabs - so none of your js is doing anything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/user78/6ajtr72x/6/     I have updated my fiddle. as said onclick active tab color is changing, but not referring to tabcontent

Comment: This line `$(this).attr('data-toggle-id')` - none of your tab links has "data-toggle-id" attribute (but then, you don't use the result...).   *"not referring to tabcontent"* - **none** of your code "refers" to "tabcontent" - not sure what you mean by that.  The page is scrolling to the content because of the basic html `<a href=#tabtwo>` and `<div id="tabtwo"` - that's how anchors (`<a>`) work.   You're not seeing the top half because your 'maintab' is sticky over the top.  You don't have any code to change the tabcontent and your existing code is hiding what is being shown.

Comment: is there any way I change the styles for div.sticky? so that my tabcontent data is shown full without hiding the data